# Python: whats does comma mean in in [ : ,1 ]

Tags: python, machine-learning

guys I am new to python and learning machine learning.I have trouble understanding what does this line of code mean:-

```
y_scores_knn = y_probas_knn[:,1]
```

I didnt get what  ,1 mean inside an array box [] and what it does

Answer (score 0):

That is how you access the column with index 1. This functionality is only if y_scores_knn is part of certain classes that deal with 2-d arrays. One class I'm most familiar with is a numpy array, which allows the accessing of columns, along with many other helpful methods.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Say for example your list is somewhat like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
```

if you do this `print(a[:,0])`
it will return [1, 2, 3]
So basically ':' means that you want to iterate through every item in the x co-ordinate

Comment: I tried this,got TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: I recommend rechecking your code - I got a error running it. It works if you convert a to np.array, but the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

if x is a two dimensional array (a matrix) then x[:,1] is the second column (all elements where the second index is 1). This notation is quite common for things like octave, matlab and numpy which have a concept of a two dimensional array.  While it does work for numpy, it will not work for a python list of lists.  A list of lists that happen to have the same number of elements is just another one dimensional list as far as python is concerned. If you want to do work with matrices and you want to use python, use numpy.